# Parse a json that contain json string

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a json which has another json inside it. But it is inside double quotes due to this it is given me a parsing error. Is there any way to parse this json other than using `gsub` to replace the double quote..

```
obj={Name:"{\"FirstName\":\"Douglas\",\"LastName\":\"Crockford\"}"}
```

I want it like this

```
{Name:{FirstName:"Douglas",LastName:"Crockford"}}
```

Is there any way to achieve this using Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `JSON.parse` on the values again:

```
obj.transform_values { |v| JSON.parse(v) }
#=> {:Name=>{"FirstName"=>"Douglas", "LastName"=>"Crockford"}}
```

When you are still on Ruby <2.4 then there a more steps:

```
obj.map { |k, v| [k, JSON.parse(v)] }.to_h
```

Comment: While I am using transform_values it is giving me an error of undefined method transform_values for string. My actual json is inside double quotes due to this it is not able to use transform_values. My actual json looks like this obj="{\"Name\":"{\"FirstName\":\"Douglas\",\"LastName\":\"Crockford\"}"}"

Comment: What version of Ruby do you use? That method is available since Ruby 2.4 that was released five years ago.

Comment: I am using ruby 2.0.0 version

Comment: I updated my answer to address Ruby 2.0. But I highly recommend that you update your application. That version is very old and might be vulnerable to well-known security issues.